# Rails & ActionCable 1.8hr network request time on localhost / High Response Time on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, puma, actioncable

The Network tab in Chrome shows `/cable` requests that fluctuate between seconds and *hours* on localhost:

[image: 1.8 hour request time]

...and then this insane domino stack of "pending" requests:

[image: DOMINOS!]

On Heroku with a Puma server and a 512 MB dyno, I get High Response Time warnings on the `/cable` endpoint. Here is an example of the log entry:

```
25 Dec 2019 14:13:31.061299 <158>1 2019-12-25T22:13:28.421009+00:00 heroku router - - at=info method=GET path="/cable" host=www.######.com request_id=#### fwd="####" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=531114ms status=101 bytes=174 protocol=https High Response Time
```

In all cases, I am the only person using the app. I've seen maybe max 3-4 other people experiencing this problem with ActionCable, but none of them seem to have any solution, and I am at my wits end. I've looked into AnyCable and Iodine, but AnyCable isn't working and Iodine does not solve my problem. What else could possibly be causing this?

**Expected behavior:** `/cable` requests should be processed in a few ms.

**Actual behavior:** some `/cable` requests are being processed 80 years later, and then hundreds of others are stuck in a `pending` state.

**System configuration:** Ruby version: 2.5.0, Rails version: 5.2.0, Puma version: 4.3.1

**channels/application_cable/channel.rb**

```
module ApplicationCable
 class Channel < ActionCable::Channel::Base
 end
end
```

**channels/application_cable/connection.rb**

```
module ApplicationCable
 class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
  identified_by :current_user

  def connect
   self.current_user = find_verified_user
   logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', current_user.username
  end

  protected
  def find_verified_user
   if verified_user = User.find_by(id: cookies.signed['user.id'])
    verified_user
   else
    reject_unauthorized_connection
   end  
  end
 end
end
```

**channels/messages_channel.rb**

```
class MessagesChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
 def subscribed
  stream_from "user_#{current_user.id}_messages_channel"
 end

 def unsubscribed
  stop_all_streams
 end

 def speak(data)
  Message.create! body: data['message'], conversation_id: data['conversation_id'], user_id: current_user.id
 end
end
```

**javascripts/channels/messages.coffee**

```
App.messages = App.cable.subscriptions.create "MessagesChannel",
 connected: ->
  console.log 'Connected'

 disconnected: ->
  console.log 'Disconnected'

 received: (data) ->
  console.log 'Received'
  $("[data-conversation-id='" + data.conversation_id + "']").append(data.message)
  console.log 'Received'
  $("#messages").append(data.message)

 speak: (message, conversation_id) ->
  @perform 'speak', message: message, conversation_id: conversation_id

$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
 submit_message()
 scroll_bottom()

submit_message = () ->
 $('#response').on 'keydown', (event) ->
  if event.keyCode is 13
   message = event.target.value
   conversation_id = $("#messages").data("conversation-id")
   App.messages.speak(message, conversation_id)
   event.target.value = ""
   event.preventDefault()

scroll_bottom = () ->
 if $('#messages').length > 0
 $('#messages').scrollTop($('#messages')[0].scrollHeight)
```

**models/messages.rb**

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
 after_create_commit { MessageBroadcastWorker.perform_async self.id }
end
```

**workers/message_broadcast_worker.rb**

```
class MessageBroadcastWorker
 include Sidekiq::Worker

 def perform(message_id)
  message = Message.find message_id
  user = message.user
  ActionCable.server.broadcast("user_#{user.id}_messages_channel", message: render_message(message, user))
 end

 private
 def render_message(message, user)
  ApplicationController.renderer.render(partial: 'messages/message', locals: { message: message, user: user })
 end
end
```

Comment: At my previous job, we dropped AC pretty quickly and went with phoenix instead. It was just way too much work to make it perform decently with today's high standards of chat applications. With that said, It's impossible to know why you have slow response times without seeing any code, could be a myriad of issues. Although, I've heard that a lot of performance-related issues with Actioncable have been solved in rails 6 (unverified), but that it requires a lot of refactoring to convert a rails 5 AC app to rails 6 AC as they dropped CoffeeScript. Probably not what you wanted to hear... But yeah.

Comment: I would switch to AnyCable, the performance is totally different and you can keep your ActionCable code base. As a biased alternative, I would also suggest the iodine WebSocket server (Ruby), which offers a custom pub/sub layer that is far superior to the AC approach.

Comment: Thank you! You're right. I can't believe there isn't much complaining about ActionCable. Hundreds of tutorials, but not one mentions the performance. I've spent the past few days setting up AnyCable. Currently having some issues setting that up (AnyCable doesn't have warden in the env), but I'm on the right path I think

Comment: @Myst thank you for making iodine!! i'm trying to set it up but get this in the stacktrace for a High Response Time alert: `2020-04-13 09:46:01.063 161 <190>1 2020-04-13T09:45:58.224726+00:00 app web.1 - - bundler: failed to load command: puma (/app/vendor/bundle/bin/puma)
2020-04-13 09:46:01.063 241 <190>1 2020-04-13T09:45:58.224772+00:00 app web.1 - - Gem::Exception: can't find executable puma for gem puma. puma is not currently included in the bundle, perhaps you meant to add it to your Gemfile?` my `puma.rb` is deleted and i have `bundle exec iodine -p $PORT -t 16 -w 4` in my Procfile

Comment: is there anything else i need to do for setup? for some reason my app is looking for puma when it should be looking for iodine

Comment: @calyxofheld - I don't have enough details to know why your application requires Puma (does `config.ru` call Puma? I don't know). However, I would start by updating the `Gemfile`, adding `iodine` as a gem. Then I'd run `bundler install` again, to update the lockfile and make sure I commit any changes I made... but that's just where I would start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to turn off the alert on Heroku logentries. The `/cable` request is *not* polling the server for updates, it's establishing a single request and then *keeping it open* until the user signs out or leaves the site.

Comment: May I have proof on this? Your answer sounds reasonable but it should be mention somewhere in the official docs